# What does it mean for something to be close to normal distribution?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

Many resources I'm learning from talk about "by this you can say that this is close to normal distribution" etc.

But none really explains what it means to be "close to normal distribution".

Why is it important to know whether something to be close to the normal distribution?
Why do we want to know how far something is off from the normal distribution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the parametric techniques in statistics assumes that the data you have is normally distributed. Since normality is an assumption then, we need to know whether the data is normal so that the assumption holds.

This is where the [central limit theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) come in as well.

By looking at a histogram, one can often say whether the data is approximately normal. You can also read up about [Student's t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution), to see how and why it is different from the normal.

When normality does not hold, another distribution can be assumed in some cases for the parametric, else on can use non-parametric techniques.

To test for normality, there are a number of tests that can be performed including the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for normality and well as the [Shapiro-Wilk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%E2%80%93Wilk_test) test. I personally prefer [QQ-plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q%E2%80%93Q_plot) though, since with these you can judge visually and the normality tests tend to be inaccurate for small samples. (On very small samples they will often conclude that the data is normal when it is in fact not). More info on that [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3693611/).

Hope this answers your question :)

Comment: "On very small samples they will often conclude that the data is normal when it is in fact not" how would you know?

Comment: I have had some experience with it recently. If you do a normality test for each of variables in the chickwts data set in R, it will say that the variables are normally distributed. By looking at the histogram or qq-plot, it is clearly not normal. Note however that this is for a small sample sizes. For larger sample sizes, these test are much more accurate in my experience @carlo

Comment: "By looking at the histogram or qq-plot, it is clearly not normal" but that's not true, is it? It is possible to draw a sample from a normal random variable so that it doesn't look normal at all. specially if the sample is little.

Comment: Yes that is a very good point indeed. But if we don't know that the population we sample from is normal, is it safe to assume that is normal just because a normality test says so?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the distribution is usually important when apllying  tests. If the distribution is normal, you can use parametric tests and if not, you use non-parametric tests. Standard normal distribution means, that the mean of the data is 0 and standard deviation is 1 etc. The gaussian curve is an example of a normal distribution. If the distribution is not normal, it means the spread data does not match the normal "bell" curve.